# Systemctl service failed Exit-code

Tags: systemd, exit-status, systemctl, watchdog

My systemctl Code dont work

```
● <appname>.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/<appname>.service; disabled; vendor prese
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-04-04 21:55:20 CEST; 4s ago
  Process: 1686 ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1686 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Apr 04 21:55:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: <appname>.service: Service RestartSec=50
Apr 04 21:55:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: <appname>.service: Scheduled restart job
Apr 04 21:55:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped <appname>.service.
Apr 04 21:55:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: <appname>.service: Start request repeate
Apr 04 21:55:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: <appname>.service: Failed with result 'e
Apr 04 21:55:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start <Appname>.service.
```

```
systemctl reset-failed <appname>
systemctl start <appname>
```

^^Dont work

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide non-truncated log lines and the unit you wrote (at the very least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is returning `203`.  That's usually a `systemd` message.

Exit codes 200 and above are used by `systemd`'s service manager to indicate problems during process invocation.

See [`man systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20Exit%20Codes) for details.

203 specifically means:

> The actual process execution failed (specifically, the execve(2) system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or non-accessible executable file.

Check that `/usr/bin/npm` actually exists and has write permissions.  Also check that you can run `/usr/bin/npm` yourself.

I usually see this problem from people who run manual installations (installing to other locations such as `/usr/local/bin` or not installing some dependencies).  Installing `nodejs` from your package manager is usually your easiest route to a working `npm`.